# Flex Mobile App StageWebView Printing

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, printing, stagewebview

I have an iphone app developed in Flash Builder/Flex Mobile Project that displays PDFs using stagewebview.

I am interested in printing these PDFs from the application.  Does any one know if this is possible and if yes could you please suggest some example code?

Thanks!

Comment: As I know, printing is not supported for air mobile. You will have to use native api through native extensions.

Answer (score 0):

[AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/) did you have a look on this.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/printing/FlexPrintJob.html

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html
With this you can read pixel by pixel and send to printer to print the Object.